# Plotting a vertical line at certain y-value of array MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, compare, axis-labels, cdf

Good day,

I have two CDF arrays that I am graphing to compare to each other. I would like to plot a line when the y value is at a certain value for both plotted arrays so that I may compare the x-value variance between the two visually.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
    [q, r] = ecdf(ray1_f);
    [w, z] = ecdf(mrc);
    plot(20*log10(r), q, 20*log10(z), w);  
    set(gca, 'YScale', 'log');
    xlabel('dB Relative to Mean');
    ylabel('Cumulative Property');
    title({'Cumulative Probability Distribution Rayleigh and 2 Branch'; 'Max Ratio Combining (filtered)'});
    legend('Rayleigh', '2 Branch Max Ratio');
    xlim([-50 0])
```

And an example of the output chart:

[image]

So, for example, I want to draw vertical lines at the two lines down to the x axis when the y value of the line is equal to 10^-1. I could then use the difference in x value between these two points to determine dB difference.

Me drawing it out in paint:

[image]

An example of this could be done with any random array, so I didn't attach more code, but just as an idea of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have two sets of plotting variables `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`. In your case

```
plot(20*log10(r), q, 20*log10(z), w);
```

Gives

```
x1 = 20*log10(r); y1 = q;
x2 = 20*log10(z); y2 = w;
```

The main task is to find the `x` value for a given `y` value, the simplest method for which is interpolation using `interp1`.

In your example, `ypoint = 10^(-1)`

```
x1point = interp1(y1, x1, ypoint);
```

This does a simple linear interpolation, there are other options which might suit you, which can be found in the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html).

Of course you need to do the same thing for `x2`,

```
x2point = interp1(y2, x2, ypoint);
```

Now plotting a vertical line is easiest with [`stem`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem.html?searchHighlight=stem&s_tid=doc_srchtitle).

```
figure; hold on;
plot(x1, y1, x2, y2);
stem(x1point, ypoint, 'marker', 'none');
stem(x2point, ypoint, 'marker', 'none');
```

Example output:

[image: stem plot]

Your "dB difference" is obviously then just `x2 - x1`, or `abs(x2 - x1)`.

---

Edit:

It might be worth noting that to simplify things further, `stem` can take vector inputs, so the whole code could be:

```
xpoints(1) = interp1(y1, x1, ypoint);
xpoints(2) = interp1(y2, x2, ypoint);
figure; hold on;
plot(x1, y1, x2, y2);
stem(xpoints, ones(size(xpoints))*ypoint, 'marker', 'none');
```

Comment: Thankyou, I was working on this after posted it and found a way to do it myself, but this is way more straightforward in some areas and shortens the code, which is good because I end up doing this multiple times for different graphs

Comment: No worries @Trever, see my edit for a little extension